# Survdiff Analysis of two genes in R

Tags: r, analysis, survival-analysis

I am trying to analyze 12 genes expression which taken from tumor patients. I need to make log-rank test by survdiff function of R language.

First, I ordered patients depending on median, first group is above the median the other one is below the median. I find p value and Kaplan Meier curve for indiviual gene by this ;

```
test <- survdiff(Surv(surv, stat) ~ genename > median(genename), data = my.Data)
```

Now I want to combine two genes and find p value by log-rank test and draw Kaplan Meier curve. These two genes have to be same for being above the median and being below the median.

I make this,

```
gene1_gene2 <- survdiff(Surv(surv, stat) ~ (gene1 > median(gene1)) + (gene2> median(gene2)), data = my.Data)

                                                      N Observed Expected (O-E)^2/E (O-E)^2/V
gene1> median(gene1)=FALSE, gene2 > median(gene2)=FALSE 70        9     24.5     9.787     17.70
gene1> median(gene1)=FALSE, gene2> median(gene2)=TRUE  19        5      6.8     0.478      0.55
gene1> median(gene1)=TRUE, gene2> median(gene2)=FALSE  19        7      4.0     2.256      2.45
gene1> median(gene1)=TRUE, gene2> median(gene2)=TRUE   69       34     19.7    10.338     16.19

 Chisq= 23  on 3 degrees of freedom, p= 3.98e-05
```

It gives 4 results but I need two results which are ;

```
gene1> median(gene1)=FALSE, gene2 > median(gene2)=FALSE
gene1> median(gene1)=TRUE, gene2> median(gene2)=TRUE
```

Because these two gives my desire. First is below the median of two and second one is above the median.

How do I do that? Please help me. I hope you understand my problem.

Best

Comment: That looks bizarre: `survdiff(Surv(surv, stat) ~ genename > median(genename), data = my.Data)`. Do you have any citations that show such a formula makes sense?

Comment: I did it by myself. I mean, I need two make patients in two groups depending on gene expression and these groups have to be done depending on median. One group is above the median and the other one must be below and equal to median. Then log rank test, I need to apply for these two groups. I made it with this approach. If you have another suggestion, I would like to hear.

Comment: I took a crack at hacking the result of a four item survdiff object but it's not particularly simple and I think you should just edit the screen output to suit your demands. You should not include the global chi-square statistic since it is calculated across the 4 groups.

Comment: But I do not know how to do that. I am very beginner of this language. can you help me? At least you can recommend a paper or book to read.

Comment: Surely you can copy and paste the text into an editor. You pasted it into the SO edit box.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using the mean expression instead of the median expression in your survival analysis since the median will split your cohort in half. From a biological standpoint, cohorts will never have exact 50% events (deaths, metastasis or any other relevant parameter of interest).

That being said, I strongly recommend you the following R code:

```
survdiff(Surv(my.Dat[,TIME],my.Dat[,EVENTS])~strata(my.Dat[,PREDICTION]),data=my.Dat)
```

where TIME is the follow-up, EVENTS are patients status (0: no event and 1: event), and PREDICTION is a column where you define expression groups. Consider the following code for filling the PREDICTION column:

```
my.Dat$PREDICTION=NA
my.Dat$PREDICTION[which(my.Dat$gene1>median(my.Dat$gene1) & my.Dat$gene2>median(my.Dat$gene2))]="UP"
my.Dat$PREDICTION[which(my.Dat$gene1<median(my.Dat$gene1) & my.Dat$gene2<median(my.Dat$gene2))]="DOWN"
```

This way you set *UP* patients having high gene1 and gene2 expressions whereas the opposite (low gene1 and gene2) are set to *DOWN*. Since other combinations (gene1 high/gene2 low and gene1 low/gene2 high) are set to NA, they won't appear in survival metrics.

Cheers.